# Как удалить подходящие элементы массива?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, разработка-игр, рекурсия

Здравствуйте! Делаю игру на подобие "Match 3". Функционал немного другой: когда игрок нажимает на определенный цвет, все такие же соседние цвета должны удалиться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно реализовать?
Вот мой код. Я думал проделать эту операцию при помощи рекурсии, но не получилось. Слишком много рекурсий - такая ошибка.

```
findNeighbours: function(bl) {
    var _self = this;

    var t = this.getTop(bl.id);
    if (t) {
        if (t.color == bl.color) {
            t.pressed = true;
            _self.findNeighbours(t);
        }
    }
    var b = this.getBottom(bl.id);
    if (b) {
        if (b.color == bl.color) {
            b.pressed = true;
            _self.findNeighbours(b);
        }
    }
    var l = this.getLeft(bl.id);
    if (l) {
        if (l.color == bl.color) {
            l.pressed = true;
            _self.findNeighbours(l);
        }
    }
    var r = this.getRight(bl.id);
    if (r) {
        if (r.color == bl.color) {
            r.pressed = true;
            _self.findNeighbours(r);
        }
    }

    return;
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (t && !t.pressed) { ...`, соответственно для `b`, `l` и `r`

Comment: Как можно прервать выполнение рекурсии, если ничего нет и продолжить поиск дальше?

Comment: Как я показал - Вы не будете обрабатывать уже обработанные клетки, и рекурсия остановится..

Comment: спасибо, заработало :)